# Prove that a function is not analytic at the origin

Tags: complex-analysis, limits, derivatives, analytic-functions

Show that the function defined by

$$f(z) = \begin{cases}
(x^3)(y^4)(x+iy) / (x^6 + y^{10}) & \text { when } z \ne 0 \\
0 & \text{ when } z = 0
\end{cases}$$

is not analytic at the origin.

First I have verified that Cauchy-Riemann equations of the given function are satisfied at the origin.

Now I tried to check the differentiability at the origin. The function is said to be differentiable at the origin if  $\lim\limits_{h\to0} \frac{ f(h) - f(0)}{ h}$ exists.

Let $h = a+ib$, after substituting $h$ in the above limit, I am stuck with

$$\lim_{ (a,b) \to(0,0) } \frac{a^3b^5}{a^6 + b^{10}}$$

I have tried to approach origin through $x$ and $y$ axis and also through $y=mx$ and $x=my$, but the value of the limit is coming out to be $0$. Please help me to solve this.

Comment: You should learn to use MathJAX for writing mathematical formulae. I've tried to update your question using MathJAX. Please check that I've not altered your intent.

Answer (score 1):

If the real (or the imaginary) part of $z$ is $0$, then $f(z)=0$. Therefore, if $f$ was differentiable at the origin, then $f'(0)=0$. On the other hand$$(\forall x\in\mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\}):\frac{f(x^4+x^3i)}{x^4+x^3i}=\frac1{1+x^6}$$and therefore if $f$ was differentiable at the origin, $f'(0)=1$. So $f$ is *not* differentiable at the origin.